# Which would be better

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 15.04

I have a msi gt70 dragon edition laptop.I want to install Ubuntu, not sure if 14.04lts or the newer 15.04 would be better considering the internal hardware...

- i7-4810mq
- Nvidia GeForce gtx 870m
- 12 gb ram
- Steelseries keyboard with programable back lighting ..

Thanks for the input

Comment: Your machine is definitely new and strong enough to handle both versions. It's up to you which version you prefer, based on how often you want to update and whether you prefer the always latest system or rather need a *very* stable system with as few changes over time as possible. Read the question linked above for more explanations.